# Level of Detail in 3D graphics - What are the pros and cons?

Tags: graphics, 3d, level-of-detail

I understand the concept of LOD but I am trying to find out the negative side of it and I see no reference to that from Googling around. The only pro I keep coming across is that it improves performance by omitting details when an object is far and displaying better graphics when the object is near.

Seriously that is the only pro and zero con? Please advice. Tnks.

Comment: "Improving Performance" is a bit of an understatement.  LOD systems in many games reduce the draw requirements from totally unmanageable levels to reasonable ones.  In a typical urban environment for a modern game, the LOD/culling system will reduce the amount of objects needing to be drawn by a factor of around 100 or more.  So by performance improvement, you're talking about something like 0.1 FPS --> 60 FPS, or the difference between "unplayable" and "buttery smooth".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOD has a variety of frameworks. What you are describing fits a distance-based framework.

One possible con is that you will have inaccuracies when you choose an arbitrary point within the object for every distance calculation. This will cause popping effects at times since the viewpoint can change depending on orientation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of LOD based on camera distance. Geometric, animation, texture, and shading variations are the most common (there are also LOD changes that can occur based on image size and, for gaming, hardware capabilities and/or frame rate considerations).

At far distances, models can change tessellation or be replaced by simpler models. Animated details (say, fingers) may simplify or disappear. Textures may move to simpler textures, bump maps vanish, spec/diffuse maps combines, etc. And shaders may also swap-put to reduce the number of texture inputs or calculation (though this is less common and may be less profitable, since when objects are far away they already fill fewer pixels -- but it's important for screen-filling entities like, say, a mountain).

The upsides are that your game/app will have to render less data, and in some cases, the LOD down-rezzed model may actually look *better* when far away than the more-complex model (usually because the more detailed model will exhibit aliasing when far away, but the simpler one can be tuned for that distance). This frees-up resources for the nearer models that you probably care about, and lets you render overall larger scenes -- you might only be able to render three spaceships at a time at full-res, but hundreds if you use LODs.

The downsides are pretty obvious: you need to support asset swapping, which can mean both the real-time selection of different assets and switching them but also the management (at times of having both models in your memory pipeline (one to discard, one to load)); and those models don't come from the air, someone needs to create them. Finally, and this is really tricky for PC apps, less so for more stable platforms like console gaming: HOW DO YOU MEASURE the rendering benefit? What's the best point to flip from version A of a model to B, and B to C, etc? Often LODs are made based on some pretty hand-wavy specifications from an engineer or even a producer or an art director, based on hunches. Good measurement is important.